# How do I migrate my Transmission torrents & settings from an old Macbook to a new one?

Tags: migration, data, torrent

How do I transfer my **Transmission 3.0 torrents, torrent data files, and colour tags/labels** from 1 Macbook Pro to another.

- My old Transmission app is in the old Macbook Pro MacOS boot ssd on a 2.5" OCZ vertex 4 ssd ~128GB. The actual torrent data files, 960 GB of anime, is on 2.5" HGST HDD 1000GB inside a macCaddy in the Superdrive slot. MacOS El Capitaine.
- I plan to remove the MacCaddy and HGST drive from the old MAcbook and place it into the new Macbook's Superdrive bay.
- The new Macbook Pro MacOS Catalina boots off a 2.5" OCZ 460 Vertex ssd ~256GB. How do I put transmission app settings into that drive and have it recognize the location of the torrents in the new HGST Hdd 1000GB drive?

Note:

1. On my old Mac I customized it so that my **Home Folder** (Documents, Downloads, Music, Photos, etc) was stored on my huge 1000GB HGST Hdd, it is **not on the MacOS boot drive**.
2. Transmission automatically puts my anime torrents in my Downloads folder so my data is targeted to go on my HGST drive automatically.
3. This setting will be important to transfer from my old Mac to my new Mac.

Answer (score 0):

1. On your New Mac you do not need to install Transmission, in fact remove it.
2. Remove the HDD caddy with your 1000GB HGST hdd from your old macbook and install it in your new Macbook
3. On your new Mac customize the location of your Home folder so it points to your HGST 1000GB hdd
4. Take out and place your old Mac Vertex 4 SSD into an external 2.5 HDD enclosure, the Nexstar CX 2.5 is a great choice
5. Attach the HDD enclosure to the USB port of your new Mac
6. On the new mac type **Migration Assistant** in the spotlight search bar and the app will find your external drive
7. Select the external drive (orange coloured) and it will find transfer your applications, files, and everything!
8. You can include/omit 3 categories before migrating: files, apps, and network settings

When you open Transmission 3.0 (yes all othe Mac apps will migrated as well) all torrent colour tags/labels and torrents will be preserved. The file integrity check will be skipped, saving your hdd from checking everything all over again.

Notes:

- Some apps on an older version of MacOS will not work once migrated to newer versions of MacOS. Download updates for them.
- Pirated apps may not work depending on how they were cracked.
- If you don't have an external hard drive enclosure, manually copy everything off your old Mac hard drive onto a usb key or external drive and it will work as well, but try to get the whole thing to fit into 1 drive. No partial transfers.